# Can't get Rails to show JSON Response for action

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem obtaining Json response, I have an action in my controller

```
def on_card
    @cart = current_cart
    @on_card = @cart.products_count 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json=> @on_card.to_json }
    end
end
```

in my application.js I try to get the response form this action
var count;

```
$.getJSON("carts/on_card", function(data){
    count = data;
});
```

when I run it firebug shows me an error:

> 404 not found
>
> rails can't find carts/on_card action

*routes for carts controller:*

```
resources :carts 

  match "carts/add/:id" => "carts#add", :as => "add"

  match "carts/add_menu/:id" => "carts#add_menu", :as => "add_menu"

match "carts/on_card" => "carts#on_card"
```

***log***:

> Started GET "/carts/on_card" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-24 20:31:58
>   +0300
>
> AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be
>   found for CartsController):

```
CartsController:
    class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def add
    if current_cart == nil
      @cart = Cart.new    
    else 
      @cart = current_cart
    end

    @cart.products << Product.find(params[:id])

    if @cart.save
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
      redirect_to root_path   
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def add_menu
    if current_cart == nil
      @cart = Cart.new
    else 
      @cart = current_cart
    end

    @cart.menus << Menu.find(params[:id])

    if @cart.save
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
      redirect_to root_path   
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end  

  def index    
    if current_cart !=nil
      @cart = current_cart
    else
      @cart = Cart.new
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end  

  def destroy
    @cart = current_cart
    @product = @cart.products.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
          format.js
    end
  end   

  def on_card
    @cart = current_cart
    @on_card = @cart.products_count 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json=> @on_card.to_json }
    end
  end
    end
```

Comment: Relative to your application directory, where is `application.js` and `carts/on_card` stored?

Comment: what you mean? application.js in public/javascripts and on_card in carts controller. I still think that problem is in action, I dlete the route to carts/on_card and try to access it form browser and rails still give me the same message: Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for CartsController

Comment: can you access carts/on_card directly from the browser?

Comment: no, I can't, unknown action error

Comment: from this error: `The action 'show' could not be found for CartsController` I think you have an issue with CartsController.

Comment: agree, but I don't understand where, it looks ok, I just added on_card method, nothing special and can't figure out what's going wrong, some guesses?

Comment: can you post up CartsController?

Comment: move `resources :carts ` to below `match "carts/on_card" => "carts#on_card"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `resources :carts` to below `match "carts/on_card" => "carts#on_card"`

You could alternatively add the action as a collection route to your `resources :carts`